# Weird .get() default

Tags: python, python-3.x

I always assumed that the default value in the `myDict.get('key', default_value)` expression was never called if the key exists in the dictionary. However, I have recently found out it somehow is. For example, consider the code

```
def doSomething(): 
    print('Done')
    return 'Another value'

myDict = {'key': 'value'}
print(myDict.get('key', doSomething()))
```

One would expect that since *key* exists in *myDict*, then the only thing `myDict.get('key', doSomething())` would do is to return *value* and hence, the function *doSomething* would never be called. This is not the case however, and running this code in python currently outputs:

```
Done
value
```

My question is: why is this the case? Why isn't the *default_value* ignored completely when the *key* exists?

And what can be done to change this, that is, to not call the *default_value* when the *key* exists?

Comment: `get` is a function. Like all python functions, the arguments will be evaluated before passing them to the function. It's not really up to `get` -- it just receives the value passed in after it's been evaluated.

Comment: The `get` method isn't some kind of macro that conditionally evaluates its arguments.  It's a method, which is a type of function.  When called, all of its arguments are evaluated and passed to the function.  That's basic to Python.

Comment: If you don't want the function to be evaluated, then you could pass the function object `myDict.get('key', doSomething)`. However, not sure the use case of that unless your valid values are also callable functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `get` method of a dictionary does not accept a callback as [Java's `computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-), but a value. If you want it to not be called, you can do it using the ternary expression:

```py
print(doSomething() if myDict.get('key') is None else myDict.get('key'))
```

Comment: Doesn't this still call `doSomething`?

Comment: @Mark Okay, but as-written, it'll still print Done and None when the value does exist

Comment: @OneCricketeer Python has an if...else expression, e.g. `v1 if cond else v2`.  In this example, the expression `v1` is only evaluated if `cond` is true, and `v2` is only evaluated if `cond` is false.  You can learn about them [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).

Comment: @OneCricketeer, yes you're right, it will print the return value of `doSomething`, which is none, but that seem like the OP's code would too if it worked the way they hoped.

Comment: @Mark It's not syntactic sugar.  It's an expression, as opposed to what you showed which is a statement that cannot be used in an expression context.

Comment: Thanks, @enzo, this is preciselly what I wanted. As for this discuss, this expression does not call the doSomething() neither does it print its return value if the key is in myDict, as I just tested it.

Answer (score 2):

The way you've written it, `doSomething()` is executed *before* `myDict.get()` is called, and its *return value* (which is implicitly `None`, because there's no return statement) is passed in as the default.

```
print(myDict.get('key', doSomething()))
# evaluates to
print(myDict.get('key', None))
# evaluates to
print('value')
```

As a rule of thumb, passing an expression as a function argument will always have the expression evaluated first, before its result is passed as that argument.

`get()` does not have the ability to *run a separate function* upon a nonexistent key. If you pass a lambda in as the default, you'd get the same lambda back out as the default, uncalled.

Comment: The question had nothing to do with the return value of doSomething(), as that would only be relevant in the case the key is not in the dictionary.  But thank you for the clarification, "passing an expression as a function argument will always have the expression evaluated first" was what I needed to realize.